# Laravel db::select() returns one string result

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a select using laravel and return with a response-json, i try:

```
public function verificaQuantidadeAnimaisAprovar(){
    $quantidade_pets_aprovar = DB::select('SELECT (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_adocao) +
        (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_encontrados) + 
        (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_perdidos)
        FROM DUAL '
    );

    return response()->json($quantidade_pets_aprovar, 201);
}
```

In the bd i have this result when i run this query:

[image]

but when i run my api in postman i receive:

> [{"(SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_adocao) +\r\n 
>   (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_encontrados) +
>   \r\n            (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM
>   cademeupet.animais_perdidos)":"36"}]

I need only the number result query: 36.

How i can fix this?

Comment: Take a look at Raw Expressions - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: any example using query builder? this examples is using eloquent, right?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function toSql() on array in file

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a whole SQL expression inside of the `select` method, which is designed to perform a select sql operation.

You should probably use the raw expression which is designed to handle complete sql queries :

```
public function verificaQuantidadeAnimaisAprovar(){
    $quantidade_pets_aprovar = DB::raw('SELECT (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_adocao) +
        (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_encontrados) + 
        (SELECT SUM(animal_pendente) FROM cademeupet.animais_perdidos)
        FROM DUAL '
    );

    return response()->json($quantidade_pets_aprovar, 200);
}
```

Note : I also changed the http code of your response because `201` (Created) indicates the creation of something, which does not seem to happen here. `200` (Ok) seems more appropriate. Be free to put `201` back if this operation creates something in your database.

Let me know if it helped you :)